# X Axis is moving down when changing y axis value in core plot

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, core-plot

I'm using coreplot for my project,the problem i'm struggling for past few hours is,i need to update the y axis values every time user enter changes value.To constraint the y axis range i'm using `[graph.defaultPlotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[graph allPlots]]`but with this i'm facing issue with x axis position,it's changing every time i change the value for y axis.
[image: The First Image]
[image: The second Image]

As you can see,the x axis is moving from down to up.How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-scaleToFitPlots:` adjusts the plot space to fit the plot data exactly. You can use it as a starting point to fit the data and then expand the resulting range to leave extra space around the edges or to fix the location of one of the ranges. For example, you could adjust the calculated `yRange` so the location is always at zero (0).

Comment: That mean i need not to call -scaleToFitPlots: every time i update the value,right ?

Comment: No, and if you know the range of data by other means (perhaps tracking the new values as they come in), you don't need to use it at all.